# ActivityNotFoundException due to wrong namespace?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

I want to start an activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FeedbackActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

In my Manifest I've declared the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".FeedbackActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="de.fun4mobile.jumba.GameActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.fun4mobile.jumba.GameActivitry" />
    </activity>
```

Still I get the above mentioned ActivityNotFoundException:

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {de.fun4mobile.jumba/de.fun4mobile.jumba.FeedbackActivity}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

It's quite obvious that the path/namespace to the activity is somehow wrong (duplicated). But why is that so? Is it an error in my manifest?

Comment: FeedbackActivity is in same package like de.fun4mobile.jumba ?

Comment: Mention packageName with before activity name in Manifestfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:value="de.fun4mobile.jumba.GameActivitry"
```

isn't `GameActivitry` a typo there?

Comment: Yes, it is. Turns out due to this typo the whole part of the XML was invalid, and thus not recognized by Android. Thus the slightly misleading error message "Unable to find explicit activity class".

Answer (score 1):

A thing is to be checked whether your src package name is same as the package name mentioned in the manifest. Only then `.FeedbackActivity` will work. Else you have to write the whole path like `src_package.filename`

For example

If your src package name is com.example and your file name is A and your manifest package name is also com.example then `android:name=.A` will be fine.

But say your manifest package is com.example2 then you have to write

```
android:name=com.example.A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".FeedbackActivity">
    <!-- ... -->
</activity>
```

Just try with this much in menifest, then I think we can know if anything wrong with this.

Comment: @rekire ok but if u will point out that error then it will be good.